# Calculating percentage steps from x length List

Tags: c#, progress

I'm creating a cusstomer progress dialog that tracks how much of a list of objects has been uploaded to a webservice. The process is as follows:

- Receive List of items that has x length (always different)
- Split the List into chunks (individual arrays) of 20 objects
- Upload chunks 1 by one (required as to not overload the webservice)
- After each chunk upload update the progress view as a percentage of the chunks so far completed up to 100%

How might i calculate the individual percentage for each chunk up to 100% based on the x length array split into chunks of 20.

Comment: processed / total = percent_completed

Comment: 100 / (total_length / 20)

Comment: @Romano that will be a constant value

Comment: @SirRufo Your are absolutely correct. A multiplication with the upload counter is necessary here: (100 / (total_length / 20)) * uploadCount

Answer (score 1):

```
// preparation
var chunkCount = (TotalItemCount - (TotalItemCount % 20)) / 20 + (TotalItemCount % 20 > 0 ? 1 : 0);
var percentage = 0.00d;

// progress
var chunkSize = ... // 20 or less for the last
var currentChunkIndex = ...
percentage += (chunkSize + (currentChunkIndex * 20)) / TotalItemCount;
```

This calculation would ensure the percentage is also correct for the last block.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible solutions:

1. Calculate progress on the completed chunks

   ```
   int count;
   int processed;
   int progress;

   var collection = Enumerable.Range(1, 111).ToList();
   var chunks = collection.Partition(20).ToList();

   Console.WriteLine("Process chunks (Progress from chunks)");

   count = chunks.Count;
   processed = 0;

   foreach (var item in chunks)
   {
       // do some actions with the chunk
       processed++;
       progress = processed * 100 / count;
       Console.WriteLine(progress);
   }
   ```

   Generated output:

   ```
   Process chunks (Progress from chunks)
   16
   33
   50
   66
   83
   100
   ```
2. Calculate progress on the completed items

   ```
   int count;
   int processed;
   int progress;

   var collection = Enumerable.Range(1, 111).ToList();
   var chunks = collection.Partition(20).ToList();

   Console.WriteLine("Process chunks (Progress from chunk.Count)");

   count = collection.Count;
   processed = 0;

   foreach (var item in chunks)
   {
       // do some actions with the chunk
       processed += item.Count();
       progress = processed * 100 / count;
       Console.WriteLine(progress);
   }
   ```

   Generated output:

   ```
   Process chunks (Progress from chunk.Count)
   18
   36
   54
   72
   90
   100
   ```

Choose the one you like most

[.net fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4hWY4t)

The `Partition` method is a custom LINQ extension

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Partition<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int partitionSize)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

        if (partitionSize <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("partitionSize");

        return source
            .Select((e, i) => new { Part = i / partitionSize, Item = e })
            .GroupBy(e => e.Part, e => e.Item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
len                     - length of the list
chunk_size = 20         - chunk size
chunk_count             - number of chunks
individual_percentage   - what percentage of all chunks is one chunk
last_percentage         - what percentage of all chunks is the last chunk 
                          which might be smaller than 20

chunk_count = len / chunk_size
chunk_count = len / 20 
individual_percentage = 100 / chunk_count
last_percentage = 100 - (individual_percentage * (chunk_count - 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find out the percentage of 20, if the total size is `n`. To get that value, you will need to calculate

```
unitSize = 100 * (20 / n);
```

Now, if you have a previous percentage, then after a chunk of 20 is completed, update it:

```
previousPercentage += unitSize;
```

where `previousPercentage` will be initialized with 0.